# Smart Contract - Display / Return all the Structure Contents

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, remix

I have a smart contract written, which stores a file ID alongwith its description.

```
struct AllFiles
 {

    string fileDesc;        //Description of a file
    uint fileId;            //Corresponding file ID
}
```

This is mapped to a uint value, which basically corresponds to the file ID here, as

> mapping (uint =>AllFiles) public allFiles;

I want to return all the contents of this mapping just like we return the entire structure array in OOP. Is there any way to do that in Solidity? I read it somewhere long back (can't find the resource now) that arrays can't be returned. But since this is a mapping, I wonder if it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mappings are not iterable. see: [mapping type documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#mappings) 
but you can build the iteration on top of it, for example: [iterable_mapping.sol](https://github.com/ethereum/dapp-bin/blob/master/library/iterable_mapping.sol) (which is a good inspiration)

IF your uint key is reliably incremented you could store something like a `filesCount` and use that in a for iteration. 
something like (pseudo code):

```
contract Files {
    struct AllFiles{
        string fileDesc;        //Description of a file
        uint fileId;            //Corresponding file ID
    }
    uint filesCount;

    mapping (uint =>AllFiles) public allFiles;

    function addFile(string _desc) {
        uint id = filesCount+1;
        allFiles[id] = AllFiles({fileDesc: _desc, fileId: id});
    }

    function iterate() {
        for(uint256 i = 1; i<=filesCount; i++) {
            allFiles[i];
        }

    }
}
```

Or you keep an array with the ids and iterate similarly over that one.

hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

@bumi says some useful things about mappings. The `for` loop jumps out as an anti-pattern because this will stop working when there are too many files.

You can make a scalable solution by pushing iteration to clients. Clients ask for rows one by one so each call to the contract is consistent in gas cost. Some ideas over here: [Are there well-solved and simple storage patterns for Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/are-there-well-solved-and-simple-storage-patterns-for-solidity)

Hope it helps.